# php mysql how to select what i need from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

how can i select data from 2 columns

i have table countrys:

```
country_id | country
--------------------
    1      | England
    2      | Poland
    3      | Italy
and more...
```

and i have table Messages:

```
message_id | message | country_id
---------------------------------
    1      |  text.. |     1
    2      |  text.. |     2
    3      |  text.. |     1
    1      |  text.. |     3
```

and i need result like this:

```
 message | country
--------------------
  text.. |  England
  text.. |  Poland
  text.. |  England
  text.. |  Italy
```

Query example please for my understand!

Comment: then you want that we do your homework?!! Please hire someone

Comment: *"how can i select data from 2 columns"* you mean from 2 "tables", *n'est-ce pas?*

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: Please, show some effort to be able to help you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes my wrong i mean from table...

Comment: dont be so rude @user3737786, we are here to help you ;-)

Comment: Only trying to help you here..

Comment: ok @user3737786 please edit your question accordingly for the title and question body. Not my downvote btw.

Comment: You will find this useful if you are trying to understand JOINs: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reading the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this as your select statement

```
SELECT message, country FROM Countrys AS c 
INNER JOIN Messages as m on c.country_id = m.country_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

```
Select message,country From Messages m join countrys c 
on m.country_id=c.country_id
```

Comment: sry, cuz lino was first.

Comment: @user3737786 : No he Lino wasn't. Recheck please.

Comment: just a bit above this answers you can sort all answers :) and there you see, that this post was faster :) @user3737786

Comment: hello friend... there is not big issue  but my answer is first :)- @user3737786

Comment: @Rahautos wow, he still picked mine, sorry man ;-)